# OpenGL,Cubemap,Vertex & FragmentShader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

New To OpenGL and i can't resolve this one. i get this error

> ERROR: 0:21: 'gl_Position' : undeclared identifier
>
> ERROR: 0:21: 'assign' :  cannot convert from '4-component vector of highp float' to 'highp float'

it also says my that my fragment shader was not compiled successfully.
I've read that it may be caused due to reading the vertex&fragment shaders wrongly . gl_Position works in previous shaders. Any input is appreciated.Thnx.

heres my skybox.vertexshader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

out vec3 TexCoords; 



uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;


//gl_Position only works with vertex &  geo shaders. from ver 1.5 to 3.3    
//gl position not compatible with frag?
//problem with shader reading thinks its the fragment



void main()
{

    gl_Position = projection * view * vec4 (position.xyz, 1.0);
    TexCoords = position; 


}
```

my skybox FragmentShader:

```
#version 330 core 



in vec3 TexCoords;


out vec4 color;


uniform samplerCube skybox;


void main()
{    

    color = texture(skybox,TexCoords);
}
```

Also the main.cpp file if that's any help:

```
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// Include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
// Include GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
GLFWwindow* window;
// Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
using namespace glm;
#include <common/skyboxtex.hpp>
#include <common/shader.hpp>
#include <common/texture.hpp>
#include <common/controls.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

int main(void)
{
    // Initialise GLFW
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Tutorial 0 - Keyboard and Mouse", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n");
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);
    // Hide the mouse and enable unlimited mouvement
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    // Set the mouse at the center of the screen
    glfwPollEvents();
    glfwSetCursorPos(window, 1024 / 2, 768 / 2);

    // Dark blue background
    //glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    // Enable depth test
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // Accept fragment if it closer to the camera than the former one
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    // Cull triangles which normal is not towards the camera
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    // Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
    GLuint programID = LoadShaders("TransformVertexShader.vertexshader", "TextureFragmentShader.fragmentshader");
    GLuint skyboxShader = LoadShaders("skybox.fragmentshader", "skybox.vertexshader");




    // Get a handle for our "MVP" uniform
    GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");
    GLuint ModelMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "M");
    GLuint ViewMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "V"); 


    // Load the texture Cube
    GLuint Texture = loadDDS("uvtemplate.DDS");






    //cubeassss

    // Get a handle for our "myTextureSampler" uniform
    GLuint TextureID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "myTextureSampler");





    float skyboxVertices[] = {
        // positions          
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,

        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,

        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,

        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,

        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f
    }




    // Our vertices. Tree consecutive floats give a 3D vertex; Three consecutive vertices give a triangle.
    // A cube has 6 faces with 2 triangles each, so this makes 6*2=12 triangles, and 12*3 vertices
    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = { 
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f
    };





    // Two UV coordinatesfor each vertex. They were created with Blender.
    static const GLfloat g_uv_buffer_data[] = { 
        0.000059f, 0.000004f, 
        0.000103f, 0.336048f, 
        0.335973f, 0.335903f, 
        1.000023f, 0.000013f, 
        0.667979f, 0.335851f, 
        0.999958f, 0.336064f, 
        0.667979f, 0.335851f, 
        0.336024f, 0.671877f, 
        0.667969f, 0.671889f, 
        1.000023f, 0.000013f, 
        0.668104f, 0.000013f, 
        0.667979f, 0.335851f, 
        0.000059f, 0.000004f, 
        0.335973f, 0.335903f, 
        0.336098f, 0.000071f, 
        0.667979f, 0.335851f, 
        0.335973f, 0.335903f, 
        0.336024f, 0.671877f, 
        1.000004f, 0.671847f, 
        0.999958f, 0.336064f, 
        0.667979f, 0.335851f, 
        0.668104f, 0.000013f, 
        0.335973f, 0.335903f, 
        0.667979f, 0.335851f, 
        0.335973f, 0.335903f, 
        0.668104f, 0.000013f, 
        0.336098f, 0.000071f, 
        0.000103f, 0.336048f, 
        0.000004f, 0.671870f, 
        0.336024f, 0.671877f, 
        0.000103f, 0.336048f, 
        0.336024f, 0.671877f, 
        0.335973f, 0.335903f, 
        0.667969f, 0.671889f, 
        1.000004f, 0.671847f, 
        0.667979f, 0.335851f
    };

    //Skybox 




    GLuint skyboxVAO, skyboxVBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &skyboxVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1,&skyboxVBO);
    glBindVertexArray(skyboxVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, skyboxVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(skyboxVertices), &skyboxVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    //skybox image faces

    std::vector <std::string>faces;
    {
            "right.BMP",
            "left.BMP",
            "top.BMP",
            "bottom.BMP",
            "front.BMP",
            "back.BMP";
    };
    GLuint CubemapTexture = loadCubemap(faces);


    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint uvbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &uvbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_uv_buffer_data), g_uv_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    do{

        // Clear the screen
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Use our shader
        glUseProgram(programID);
        glUseProgram(skyboxShader);

        // Compute the MVP matrix from keyboard and mouse input
        computeMatricesFromInputs();
        glm::mat4 ProjectionMatrix = getProjectionMatrix();
        glm::mat4 ViewMatrix = getViewMatrix();
        glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
        glm::mat4 MVP = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;




        // Send our transformation to the currently bound shader, 
        // in the "MVP" uniform
        glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);

        // Bind our texture in Texture Unit 0
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
        // Set our "myTextureSampler" sampler to use Texture Unit 0
        glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);









        // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            0,                  // stride
            (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );

        // 2nd attribute buffer : UVs
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            1,                                // attribute. No particular reason for 1, but must match the layout in the shader.
            2,                                // size : U+V => 2
            GL_FLOAT,                         // type
            GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
            0,                                // stride
            (void*)0                          // array buffer offset
        );

        // Draw the triangle !
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12*3); // 12*3 indices starting at 0 -> 12 triangles

        //cube



        //cube
        glm::mat4 ModelMatrix2 = glm::mat4(1.0);
        ModelMatrix2 = glm::translate(ModelMatrix2, glm::vec3(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        glm::mat4 MVP2 = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix2;

        glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP2[0][0]);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ModelMatrix2[0][0]);


        // 2nd object
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12 * 3);


        // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

        // 2nd attribute buffer : UVs
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);   

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        //newshit


        //skybox matrix
        glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(glm::mat3(getViewMatrix()));


        //  skybox Uniform                      INCLUDE glm value_PTR.hpp

        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(skyboxShader, "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(skyboxShader, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(ProjectionMatrix));



        glBindVertexArray(skyboxVAO);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
        glUseProgram(skyboxShader);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, CubemapTexture);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);



        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
           glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );

    // Cleanup VBO and shader
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &uvbuffer);
    glDeleteProgram(programID);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &TextureID);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);

    // Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the host code that compiles this at runtime?

Comment: Why on Earth are y'all voting to close this? It's a fair question.

Comment: Post the implementation of `LoadShaders`.

Comment: Also, you might like at the `SOIL2` library - it provides methods for (easily) loading cubemaps.

Comment: GLuint LoadShaders(const char * vertex_file_path, const char * fragment_file_path. this is implemented in my shader.cpp file.

Comment: I noticed that in your calls to `LoadShaders`, on one line you're passing the vertex shader first, but on the second you're passing the fragment shader first. Assuming that the `LoadShaders` expects a VS in one spot and the FS in the other, one of these calls is attempting to compile a vert shader as a frag shader, and the other is doing the opposite.

Comment: @Hauk That's not the implementation. That's a declaration, which is basically useless for debugging.

Comment: yeah. i suspected there was a problem with how my shader.cpp file read the vertex&fragmentshader. i'll look into it.Thnx

Comment: @Hauk See my answer. Your parameter orders are mismatched in the `LoadShaders ` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See

```
GLuint programID = LoadShaders("TransformVertexShader.vertexshader", "TextureFragmentShader.fragmentshader");
GLuint skyboxShader = LoadShaders("skybox.fragmentshader", "skybox.vertexshader");
```

One of these calls is sending the vertex shader source first, while the other is sending the fragment shader source first.

Unless `LoadShaders` can magically tell by examining the source which one is which - perhaps, by looking for the occurrence of `gl_Position` in the source, which is invalid in fragment shaders - then you need to swap the parameter order on one of these calls.